# why does obj?.foo(); pass eslint no-unsafe-optional-chaining

Tags: eslint

when trying to call a method of a variable, if `obj` is `undefined`, the code `obj?.foo()` can stops normally

but when `obj` is a object, code like below will throw error

```js
let obj = {};
obj?.foo(); // TypeError: obj?.foo is not a function
```

and the "safer" syntax could be `obj?.foo?.()`

why doesn't eslint process this rule in a "safer" way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but eslint is simply not doing typechecks. See for example [this issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/352). Without typechecks, the snippet you posted should be valid code.

Now the rule you mentioned does not apply here. It is specifically for cases, where the use of the optional chaining operator *itself* might cause problems, even if typing was correct. There are a lot of examples [in the eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unsafe-optional-chaining). In the example snippet however, there is no problem in the use of the optional chaining operator, in fact it does not even have an effect here. You could as well write `obj.foo()`, which again requires typechecks to be identified as invalid code.

To use type checks, run your code through the typescript transpiler:

```
 error TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

In fact you can use `tsc` as linter as well, see the linked issue.